# Differences between the 3 comparison method of MatchShapes (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I am using OpenCV function matchShapes and I wonder what are the differences between the 3 comparison methods `CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1` , `CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I2` and `CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I3` in [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#matchshapes)

Are there cases where it is better to use a particular method ?

Also, Why for `CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1` and `CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I2` the sum is calculated and for `CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I3` only the maximum is taken into account ?

Comment: The difference is explained in the documentation. You need to understand Hu moments to understand the terminology for each method.